# How to merge two 3d coordinate systems? Data from two Azure Kinect Cameras - Calibration

Tags: python-3.x, 3d, coordinate-systems

I have to analyze data from two Azure Kinect cameras. Before every measurement we had a calibration sequence where the subjects stands for 15 seconds in a T-position without moving.

For every frame I have 32 3d coordinates (= 32 body joints) in both coordinate systems. This means for example: camera1: LEFT_KNEE =  x1,y1,z1  and camera2: LEFT_KNEE =  x2,y2,z3 --> for 32 body joints.

Now, I have to find the best translation (T) and rotation (R) matrices for the best alignment.

My idea is to find the best T and R for each frame and then calculate a mean T and mean R out of it to get one final T and R I can apply for other datasets (same subject, same camera position).

I already have a code and it runs. I also let plot the same data in the 3d system in 3 different point of views to check how the transformed point clouds look ins space / if the clouds are really aligned.

BUT it seems as the clouds are not aligned correctly ... in my opinion a simple rotation in one axe would be improve the result a lot. I already tried to adjust it "manual" by trial and error but it doesnt work as well.

I also thought about if the data are maybe mirrored and that this is the reason why it is not possible to finde a more perfect transformation but I double checked this and the data are definitely correct.

I understand the single steps of the calculation but I am not completely familiar with the math behind the calculation. I tried some different methods but the result is nearly the same.

Does anybody know a little more about this topic? I am open for other solutions as well. I also tried it with open3d. It also runs and shows me (similar) results but there I absolutely not understand what is going on "behind" the scenes, so i decided for this way ...

```
import json
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

    

def calculate_transform_matrices(m_points_array, s_points_array):
    # centroids of the point sets
    centroid1 = np.mean(m_points_array, axis =0)
    centroid2 = np.mean(s_points_array, axis =0)

    centroid1 = m_points_array[0]
    centroid2 = s_points_array[0]

    # point sets centered around their centroids
    centered_m_points = m_points_array - centroid1
    centered_s_points = s_points_array - centroid2

    # Ccovariance matrix
    covariance_matrix = np.dot(centered_s_points.T, centered_m_points)

    # singular value decomposition (SVD)
    U, _, Vt = np.linalg.svd(covariance_matrix)

    # rotation matrix = R
    R = np.dot(Vt.T, U.T)

    # translation vector = T
    T = centroid1 - np.dot(R, centroid2)

    return R, T


JOINTANZAHL = 32
KNOCHENANZAHL = 33

#############################################################
first_sub = 24

last_sub = 27

start_frame = 150
last_frame = 300

m= "master"
s= "subord"

#####################################################################################
## open the need files from master and suprd
#####################################################################################   
 
for SUBJECT in range(first_sub, last_sub+1):
    m_file = "s"+str(SUBJECT)+"_calib_popup_"+str(m)+"_"
    s_file = "s"+str(SUBJECT)+"_calib_popup_"+str(s)+"_"

    with open(str(m_file)+".json",  'r') as f:
        m_dataset = f.read()
    
    with open(str(s_file)+".json",  'r') as f:
        s_dataset = f.read()

    m_obj = json.loads(m_dataset)
    s_obj = json.loads(s_dataset)

#####################################################################################
## Calculating the R and T for each frame --> then calculate the mean frame out of all frame Rs and Ts
#####################################################################################   
    
    
    rotation_matrices = []
    translation_vectors = []

    for frame in range(start_frame,last_frame):
        m_points_lst = []
        s_points_lst = []
        
        for joint in range (JOINTANZAHL):
            m_points = m_obj['frames'][frame]['bodies'][0]['joint_positions'][joint]
            s_points = s_obj['frames'][frame]['bodies'][0]['joint_positions'][joint]


            m_points_lst.append(m_points)
            s_points_lst.append(s_points)

        m_points_array = np.array(m_points_lst)
        s_points_array = np.array(s_points_lst)

        R, T = calculate_transform_matrices(m_points_array, s_points_array)
        
        rotation_matrices.append(R)
        translation_vectors.append(T)
               
    mean_R = np.mean(rotation_matrices, axis=0)
    mean_T = np.mean(translation_vectors, axis=0)

#####################################################################################
## Use the mean R and T to transform the original into the aligned data (master & subord)
#####################################################################################   
    
    ## aligned point clouds 
    subord_aligned_joint_positions = []
    master_aligned_joint_positions = []

    for frame in range(start_frame, last_frame):
        m_points_lst = []
        s_points_lst = []

        for joint in range (JOINTANZAHL):
            m_points = m_obj['frames'][frame]['bodies'][0]['joint_positions'][joint]
            s_points = s_obj['frames'][frame]['bodies'][0]['joint_positions'][joint]

            m_points_lst.append(m_points)
            s_points_lst.append(s_points)

        m_points_array = np.array(m_points_lst)
        s_points_array = np.array(s_points_lst)
        
        R = mean_R
        T = mean_T
        
         
        
        aligned_s_points = np.dot(s_points_array, R.T) + T
        
        ## possibilty to change/adjust the R of one point cloud 
        #R = np.dot(R, np.array([[-1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [-0.9, 0, 1]]))
      
        aligned_m_points = np.dot(m_points_array, R.T) + T
  
        subord_aligned_joint_positions.append(aligned_s_points)
        master_aligned_joint_positions.append(aligned_m_points)
    
    ## here we print one example point e.g. frame 9 = hand 
    print("sub: first frame, joint9 : " +str(subord_aligned_joint_positions[0][8]))
    print("master: first frame, joint9 : " +str(master_aligned_joint_positions[0][8]))
    
    
#####################################################################################
## Calculating the mean error --> how precise the data were aligned
#####################################################################################  
    
    
    errors = []
    
    for frame in range(len(subord_aligned_joint_positions)):
        for joint in range(JOINTANZAHL):
            subord_joint_pos = subord_aligned_joint_positions[frame][joint]
            master_joint_pos = master_aligned_joint_positions[frame][joint]
            
            error = np.sqrt(np.mean((subord_joint_pos - master_joint_pos)**2))
            errors.append(error)

    rmse = np.mean(errors)
    print("the RMSE is: "+str(rmse))
    
    
#####################################################################################
## Plot in three different point of views
#####################################################################################
    
    angles = [(0, 90), (0, 0), (90, 0)]

    visualization_frames = [1]

    fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(15, 10), dpi=200, subplot_kw={'projection': '3d'})
enter image description hereenter image description here
    for i, ax in enumerate(axes):
        elevation_angle, azimuth_angle = angles[i]
        
        for frame in visualization_frames:
            for joint in range(JOINTANZAHL):
                subord_joint_pos = subord_aligned_joint_positions[frame][joint]
                master_joint_pos = master_aligned_joint_positions[frame][joint]

                ax.scatter(subord_joint_pos[0], subord_joint_pos[1], subord_joint_pos[2], c='r', marker='o')
                ax.scatter(master_joint_pos[0], master_joint_pos[1], master_joint_pos[2], c='b', marker='o')

                ax.text(subord_joint_pos[0], subord_joint_pos[1], subord_joint_pos[2], str(joint), color='r')
                ax.text(master_joint_pos[0], master_joint_pos[1], master_joint_pos[2], str(joint), color='b')

        ax.set_xlabel('X')
        ax.set_ylabel('Y')
        ax.set_zlabel('Z')
        ax.view_init(elevation_angle, azimuth_angle)
        
    fig.text(0.5, 0.2, "RMS = "+str(rmse), ha='center')
    fig.text(0.5, 0.17, "translation", ha='center')
    fig.text(0.5, 0.15, str(T), ha='center')
    fig.text(0.5, 0.11, "rotation", ha='center')
    fig.text(0.5, 0.05, str(R), ha='center')
    
    plt.suptitle("s"+str(SUBJECT)+" calibration - Frame: "+str(visualization_frames), fontsize=16)
    
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

`

I try to align two point clouds with same amount of points and with relativ equal position in space.

The two point clouds are originally located in different 3d systems.

Goal is to bring the point clouds into one 3d system and transform the orientation of the clouds until the distance between the corresponding points is small.

At the end there should be two point clouds in one 3d system and the point clouds should be aligned.

The current status: All steps work but by eye the point clouds seems not be aligned pretty well.

Question: mistake in code or problem in data[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyLE7.png)

Comment: Hi, interesting problem! I'm not familiar with the underlying approach, but assuming that part is sound, I would generate some dummy test data eg. maybe a cube ?, then rotate/ translate the data to form the other point cloud and inject it into your calculate_transform_matrices() function - I'm thinking that way you can hopefully eliminate the data and can verify the code.

Comment: I would suggest looking at using better data triage, the issue with average is that if you have massive outliars, then your end result will be skewed. You're using real-life data, and that data is going to have errors. I'm not super familiar with this topic, but that'd be my first thought.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the advices, it helped a lot. I think I was able to find the problem. I applied the transformation on both datasets but actually the R and T is the transformation of one datasets into the other original. So when I just transform dataset 1, then it is like the other original dataset2. The results are way better now!